# Which preposition do I use in translating: I wish I could go to Germany today

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I will heute Deutschland (preposition?) gehen/fliegen.

Comment: Welcome to the site. "Officially," you're not supposed to ask for a translation. But you are allowed to ask about grammar. So I tweaked the question by adding a reference to a preposition. That's what you should ask about. – Tom Au just now edit 
a

Answer (score 6):

> Ich wünschte, ich könnte heute **nach** Deutschland gehen/fliegen/fahren/reisen.

The "gehen/fliegen/fahren/reisen" part may depend on how far away you are. "To go" normally means simply "gehen".

If you want to educate yourself and like to read humour, read Mark Twain's "The awful German language". The important part is, the actual verb "to go" is at the end.

Comment: The different verbs don't differe in the distance travelled. They differ in the way or aim of travelling: `gehen` = `to walk` or the most general form in casual language. `fliegen` = `to fly` which means using lift and recoil to move through air. `fahren` =`to drive/sail/balloon` which means using buoyancy or contact forces to keep an equilibrium in a fluid or on a surface and use recoil to accelerate. `reisen`=`to travel` move with the aim of tourism.

Answer (score 0):

> I will heute Deutschland (preposition?) gehen/fliegen.

Use `nach` and put the preposition before the destination.
I think this is why it is named ***pre-/prä-position***

> I will heute **nach** Deutschland gehen/fliegen.